# How to make Veins 5.2 work with Omnet 6.0.2

Tags: omnet++, veins, sumo

I get this error when running in Ubuntu, how can we make it work?

TraCIScenarioManager connecting to TraCI server

> <!> TraCI server reports unsupported TraCI API version: 21. We recommend using Sumo version 1.0.1 or 0.32.0 -- in module (veins::TraCIScenarioManagerLaunchd) RSUExampleScenario.manager (id=6), at t=0s, event #1

[Error Message Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lkDmK.png)